# Brother dcp t510w problem

Tags: 22.04, printing

Since I have kernel 6.5, my system does not see the Brother dcp t510w printer via WiFi. It is only detected via USB. What could have happened? I didn't have this problem before. The problem affects Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: try ``lpinfo -v''

Comment: The printer is not detected via WiFi at all, only via USB. There was no problem before updating to kernel 6.5.